# heroku receiving Application Error. no web processes

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

**i am having this problem on my heroku server**

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

**i attempted to run**

heroku ps:scale web=1

**but receive this error**

Scaling web processes... failed
 !    No such type as web

heroku ps:restart web.1 --app dashboardaudi88
Restarting web.1 process... done

**and here are the heroku logs**

```
heroku logs
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options:                     mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   rails new APP_PATH [options]
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Description:
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: sqlite3
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1
]: Options:
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: jquery
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Runtime options:
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Example:
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     See the README in the newly created application to get going.
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Rails options:
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
2012-12-08T21:14:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     defaults values shown above in this help message.
2012-12-08T21:14:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-12-08T21:14:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-12-08T21:23:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-12-08T21:24:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 37045`
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: sqlite3
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options:         mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Options:
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage:
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  # Default: jquery
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Description:
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   rails new APP_PATH [options]
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
2012-12
-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     defaults values shown above in this help message.
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Example:
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     See the README in the newly created application to get going.
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Runtime options:
2012-12-08T21:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Rails options:
2012-12-08T21:24:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-12-08T21:24:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-12-08T21:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Comment: Is `web` defined in your `Procfile`? Heroku uses `foreman` to manage process types.

Comment: so i added a procfile and am now able to run heroku ps:scale web=1 but am receiving this error now     heroku ps
=== web: `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`
web.1: crashed 2012/12/08 11:07:50 (~ 3m ago)

Comment: this is what my profile looks like                                 web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

Comment: What's in the logs? `heroku logs -t --app APP_NAME`?

Comment: heroku logs -t --app dashboardaudi88
2012-12-08T20:23:22+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
2012-12-08T20:23:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
2012-12-08T20:23:22+00:00 app[web.1]:       [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository        
and it goes on for another 50+lines

Comment: More? Please have logs open while restarting the `web.1`: `heroku ps:restart web.1 --app APP_NAME` and put the logs as a code in edited question.

Comment: ran the heroku ps:restart web.1 --app and posted my results above

Comment: Do I understand correctly? Do you try to run `rails new` directly on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Procfile doesn't have any extension! For instance if you use Procfile.txt it's gonna return "Scaling web processes... failed ! No such type as web". Delete the extension of your Procfile and it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running, you should run: `heroku ps:scale web=1`, which fixed the error for me